# ¿Cómo puedo usar la libreria php_pdo_sql srv en linux debian?

Tags: sql-server, sqlsrv, php-5.6

Estoy tratando de conectarme a sql server express 2019 con php 5.6 usando la libreria php_pdo_sqlsrv, mi sitema operativo es linux debian

He buscado bastante la libreria `php_pdo_sqlsrv` para la versión de php 5.6 de linux y no lo encuentro por nungún lado, ¿existe algún repositorio en donde puede ubicar esa libreria? si alguien lo sabe podria ayudarme a encotrarlo, recientemente he tratado de instalarlo con este comando en la terminal pero he podido instalarlo me un error donde dice que `no se ha podido localizar el paquete`

```
apt-get install php5.6-php_pdo_sqlsrv
```

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo que justifique seguir usando PHP 5? Pronto esta versión cumplirá 20 años y está prácticamente en desuso hoy día.

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-debian) siempre suele ser el camino feliz, porque son otros desarrolladores tratando de que no les lleguen quejas porque no se entiende lo que hicieron :)

Al día de hoy, esa documentación dice que es algo como

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -v 8.1 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

Pero es importante revisar el enlace para revisar y confirmar TODOS los prerrequisitos que indican.